# Laravel Pass Data to controller through ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to send 2 variables to `FavorisController`: `{{ Auth::user()->id }}` and the `id` that I have in the URL

This is what I've tried so far

Route:

```
Route::get('annonce_test/{id}','FavorisController@create' );
```

My ajax script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.favoris').click(function(){                  
        var id_user = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}" ;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'annonce_test/{id}',
            type: 'GET',             
            data: {id: 1, id_user: $id_user},
            success: function(data){
                alert(Ajouter au Favoris avec succes);
            },
            error: function(){},
        });""
    });         
});
```

FavorisController

```
public function create(Requests $request)
{
    $id_annonce = $_GET['id'];
    $id_user = $_GET['id_user'];
    $query = DB::table('annonce_residentiel_user')
    ->insertGetId(
        array('annonce_residentiel_id' => $id_annonce , 'user_id' => $id_user)
        );
}
```

I got the error trying to get property of non-object `{{ Auth::user()->id }}`

But is this the correct way to do it? I mean if I have another script for deleting I should chage the url in my ajax script.

Comment: Is the user logged in? If not, there is no id. Also, you have the URL incorrect in your ajax. You need to append id_user to the URL instead of using `{id}`

Comment: You will also need to pass the CSRF token. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)      <script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
</script>

Comment: Oh you're right now I can acces to the page. But it don't execute the ajax code I tried an alert but nothing shows up

Comment: But It's not the id_user I want in the url it's the id_annonce

Answer (score 1):

Move `Auth::user()` part from JS script to PHP:

```
->insertGetId(['annonce_residentiel_id' => $id_annonce , 'user_id' => auth()->user()->id]);
```

Also, make sure user is authenticated with something like:

```
if (auth()->check()) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Comment: That's correct I guess I have the error in my ajax code : data attribute

Answer (score 0):

Based on your route definition $id is the argument for the create method and to get more data from the ajax call you should use Input::get. Also the route will be activated only when the url in the ajax call has the format of ex: annonce_test/25. check the update to the ajax call.

Route:

```
    Route::get('annonce_test/{id}','FavorisController@create' );
```

Ajax call:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.favoris').click(function(){                  
         var id_user = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}" ;
         $.ajax({
             url: 'annonce_test/'+id_user,
             type: 'GET',
             data: {id: 1},
             success: function(data){
                 alert(Ajouter au Favoris avec success);
             },
             error: function(){},
       });
     });         
     });
```

FavorisController:

```
    public function create($id)
    {
        $id_annonce = Input::get['id'];
        $query = DB::table('annonce_residentiel_user')->insertGetId(
          array('annonce_residentiel_id' => $id_annonce , 'user_id' => $id));
    }
```